# How to check if the main domain matches a certain domain and then redirect the request in .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

What I want to accomplish is that when the user tries to visit the site with url like the following :

https://test.canvas-events.co.uk/

so it should redirect to :

http://test.canvas-events.co.uk/

With the whole URI and then if user visits the following url as the following :

http://www.canvas-events.co.uk OR http://canvas-events.co.uk

so it should redirect to :

https://www.canvas-events.co.uk

I have tried with the following code but it redirects all requests to test.canvas-events.co.uk as :

```
# Avoid use of HTTPS for TEST SERVER
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^test.canvas-events.co.uk [NC,OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://test.canvas-events.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

# Redirect all www or non www to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}::%{HTTP_HOST} ^off::(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

**NOTE :** I want to redirect with the whole URI not just to the main domain links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am missing something you can simplify this by using:

```
RewriteEngine On

## Avoid use of HTTPS for TEST SERVER

# if current host is test
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.canvas-events\.co\.uk$ [NC]
# and if HTTPS is turned on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
# redirect to non-HTTPS version
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

## Redirect all www or non www to https

# if HTTPS is off
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
# OR if current host canvas-events.co.uk (non-www)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^canvas-events\.co\.uk$ [NC]
# redirect to https and www
RewriteRule ^ https://www.canvas-events.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Make sure to use a new browser for testing.

Comment: You are a savior, Thank you so much! Looks like now I can see what was I missing, Can you a bit explain as well what's happening in these lines?

Comment: Added comments before each line.

Comment: Thanks once again. So the dots (.) in the url needs to be escaped right?

Comment: Yes, otherwise dot in a regex matches any character.